# ASP.NET Postbacks x jQuery: What are the cons and pros?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I'll start some lab prototypes on some of our Web App pages. We use a lot of Postback, ViewState, UpdatePanels, ModalPopup Extenders, all the ASP.NET usual stuff. It's good enough for most cases. But I wanna push things further...

I've been playing around with jQuery for some time now. I know what's capable of. I'm thinking of TRULY substituting the ASP.NET usual things by things like `$.ajax()`, `$.get()`, etc. No more postbacks. User interface? jQuery UI. I'm truly impressed by some plugins, specially jQuery grid.

I think it's the next step into Web UI. I mean, it's ALREADY the current step! I love the power of C#, but I'm not that impressed with the ASP.NET framework. I imagine that by doing that, I'll truly separate UI from Business logic.

However:

- Should I really do it?
- Should the code behind be only Web Handlers and Web Services?
- What should I beware of?
- How about security? How to implement it?
- What will I gain? I know I'll gain some in performance, since postbacks in pages with too much data takes time because of the ViewState AND I'll be transacting only XML and/or the always light JSON format. But I imagine, as usual, there will be pain...
- Where will the pain be?

I'll take it slow, anyway. But I want to ask you guys: what am I getting into here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before I reply, I would strongly suggest that you go for ASP.NET MVC Framework. It's a totally different kind of development than the Webforms. It's a step away from ViewState and that junk. This is where Microsoft is pushing all their efforts to and this is the only way right now to build much more scalable and interactive websites on the .NET Stack.

**Should I really do it?**
Yes. jQuery + Ajax are very good and would let you build some very interactive and usable websites. And the way things are going right now, truth to speak if you don't use the power of Javascript at the client-side, your website would like build in 1995.

**Should the code behind be only Web Handlers and Web Services?**
You should only use the handlers/services to improve the design of your page. You can't build your whole website only on that. The method is to create a page, and then improve it with the services. Avoid postbacks for small details. And improve speed by Ajax etc. Making a whole website on Ajax is not a good idea.

**What should I beware of?**
Technically you need to understand client-side coding and how does HTTP works over the internet. ASP.NET takes does that all under the hood, so you don't even need to know but if you are doing postbacks etc. then you should understand it's limitations etc.

**How about security? How to implement it?**
There isn't a lot to security in Ajax as long as you do the same stuff which you did for normal postbacks e.g.s CSS attacks, SQL injections, Anti-Forgery etc.

**What will I gain? I know I'll gain some in performance, since postbacks in pages with too much data takes time because of the ViewState AND I'll be transacting only XML and/or the always light JSON format. But I imagine, as usual, there will be pain...
Where will the pain be?**
The pain usually is the complexity. But complexity comes with flexibility. Traditional ASP.NET was taking care of everything without you having to interfere. but now you have to make up the request, send it to server, receive the reply and then update DOM accordingly. You have to deal with all of that but on the flip side, you can deal it in whatever you want.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I say yes.  Postbacks are easy for the developer and horrible for the user experience.  Don't make them suffer through heavy page loads just to toggle a box on the page.

But, you need to consider the time that it will take, especially since you might have to rely on more and more javascript code (which can be finicky if you are new to it).

I've recently done it on a large project and I'm glad I did it.  I moved from full page postbacks to WebMethods and web services.  Try to reduce state on the server which will help compartmentalize each request handler.

Comment: How about security? How did you stop outsiders from accessing your WebMethods/WebServices?

Comment: You don't.  You handle authentication on the server.  You can't keep a user from hitting your web service.  You can only keep them out through account authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Look into [asp.net-MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc) it is most likely what you are talking about and implements jquery and JSON calls.

Comment: That sounds promising... I've heard of it, but I do not really know: Is ASP.NET MVC a Framework? Or it it a process Guideline?

Comment: I added a link to the answer so you can read about it.  MVC is a design practice.  It seperates the UI Logic from the Data Model.  If you use VS2010 it is included (at least in professional) there is a patch/plugin for VS2008.

Answer (score 0):

If you used PostBack and ViewState you might have done that for a reason. It allows for Components and Events. Thats something you will miss in ASP.NET MVC (you dont say you want to use ASP.NET MVC, but if you say ASP.NET without PostBack everyone will understand ASP.NET MVC)

I use ASP.NET and ASP.NET MVC. ASP.NET with postback comes into play if the project is realy more an application than a website (lets say nyt.com being a website and facebook being an application ).